# Nesting tests in a single Nightwatch test suite to use multiple befores

Tags: nightwatch.js

I have a set of tests in a suite that I want to run across many page objects. I tried building a test object like below, except it only runs the first one.

```
module.exports = {
  'test1': {
    before: function() { console.log('before1'); },
    'test 1a': function() { console.log('test1a'); }
  },
  'test2': {
    before: function() { console.log('before2'); },
    'test 1a': function() { console.log('test2a'); }
  }
};
```

Is it possible to do this kind of nesting in one test suite? The actual use case I want to achieve is like this:

```
['page1', 'page2'].forEach(page => {
  this[`Do something on ${page}`] = {
    before: client => {
        client.page[page].navigate();
    },
    'it does something': client => {
        client.page[page]().expect.section('@element').visible;
    }
 }
```

where I want to build dynamic test suites that run the same tests on many "page" objects.

**UPDATE:** I really want to continue using the Nightwatch runner instead of using another runner like Mocha that indeed does have this functionality.

Comment: i dont think it is good design, we should separate the test cases,make it  . In any test case i have done, they are required a lot page-object in before/after (precondition and clean stuff after test).So better make it simple as possible

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this you need to change the nightwatch.json config to use other test runner in this case mocha to have more flexibility:

```
"test_runner" : {
 "type" : "mocha",
 "options" : {
  "ui" : "bdd",
  "reporter" : "spec"
 }
}
```

and then you can write your tests like this:

```
describe('describe', function() {

  before(function(cl, done) {
    ng = ng({client: cl, screen: 'rounding'});
    client = cl;

    console.log('before1')

    done();
  });

  after(function(client, done) {
    if (client.sessionId) {

        client
        .pause(1999)
        .end(function() {
            done();
        });
    } else {
        done();
    }
  });

  afterEach(function(client, done) {
    done();
  });

  beforeEach(function(client, done) {
    done();
  });

  describe('describe nested', function () {
    before(function (client, done) {
        console.log('before before!')
        done();
    });

    it('expectation', function (client) {
      goToRoundingPage(client);
      client.pause(111);
    });
  });
});
```

As you can see with this testrunner you can nest the tests the times you want and support nested befores/after etc

Comment: I wanted to avoid Mocha as that is indeed what I was using originally but you lose some other Nightwatch functionality if you do this so have opted back. I was hoping Nightwatch runner would let you but it doesn't. I will update my questions specifying that I don't want to use a different runner. Thanks!

Comment: Ok no problem and yes, I'm thinking to roll back to nightwatch runner too because the reporter is not showing all the passed assertions in mocha

Comment: @matt-derrick, please add in your edit the word "Updated " and add the date, to not invalidate my question.